# Using Fetch API to read HTTP response body from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that needs to intercept HTTP response data. I was looking at a similar extension but I couldn't understand the following part of the code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var oldXHR, stateChangeHandler, prop;

  oldXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest;
  stateChangeHandler = function (evt) {

    const constantMock = window.fetch;
    window.fetch = function() {

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          constantMock.apply(this, arguments)
              .then((response) => {
                  if (response.bodyUsed) {
                    resolve(response);
                  } else {
                    var mockResponse = response.clone().json();

                    mockResponse.then(function(result){
                      handleData(result);
                    });
                    resolve(response);
                  }
              })
              .catch((error) => {
              })
          });
    }
  };

  function newXHR() {
    var xhr = new oldXHR();
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', stateChangeHandler);
    return xhr;
  }

  // Copy original states and toString
  for (prop in oldXHR)
    newXHR[prop] = oldXHR[prop];

  window.XMLHttpRequest = newXHR;
})();
```

I was looking at Fetch API documentation online but in every example I found, there needed to be a specific url for it to work (ex: fetch("some url").then().catch()). How does the above fetch call work with no parameters? What is it fetching from?

Separate questions - How does const constantMock = window.fetch work? How does apply() work?

Also, is there a way to intercept JSON data from a web socket connection with a chrome extension as well? The pasted code only works with a long polling connection with the server.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For `constantMock = window.fetch`, please understand in JS functions are first class objects - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function - and for how apply works see  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: @YK1 Thank you! I realized I left out the main part of my question and just updated my post

Comment: [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is not a random name either.